# How to get values from the specified range and store it in a String array (excel VBA)

Tags: vba

In my Excel Sheet am having a cell(say B4) in which I will type the range of cells that I want to select(say D4:D7), now once the button is pressed using macro i should get the values in the respective cells in the range and to store it in a array.  How can I do this?

Can anyone help me with a VBA code. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can assign a Range to an Array directly:

```
Dim ary() As Variant
ary = Range(Range("B4").Value)
```

Answer (score 0):

Say you type your range in cell B4:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target as Range) 
    If Target.Address = "$B$4" Then

        Dim rangeAddress As String
        rangeAddress = Range("B4").Text

        Dim arr() As Variant
        arr = Range(rangeAddress)

    End If
End Sub
```